# I want to keep the file upload optional but the form is not submitting if file is not uploaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I've created a form where I want the file upload to be optional, it's in React & React Bootstrap. But when I don't upload the file the form is not being submitted.

I'm using a custom form validation, and it works fine. Also, here I'm trying to upload the single file to the backend, which is also working fine. But I am not able to submit the form without file upload.

```
const Contact = () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);
  const [successful, setSuccessful] = useState(false);
  const [form, setForm] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const setField = (field, value) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [field]: value,
    });

    if (!!errors[field])
      setErrors({
        ...errors,
        [field]: null,
      });
  };

  const { firstName, lastName, email, city, company, howCanWeHelp, NDA } = form;

  const findFormErrors = () => {
    const newErrors = {};

    if (!firstName || firstName === "") newErrors.firstName = "cannot be blank";
    if (!lastName || lastName === "") newErrors.lastName = "cannot be blank";
    if (!email || !email.includes("@")) newErrors.email = "enter a valid email";
    if (!company || company === "") newErrors.company = "cannot be blank";
    if (!howCanWeHelp || howCanWeHelp === "")
      newErrors.howCanWeHelp = "cannot be blank";

    return newErrors;
  };

  const onFileUpload = async (e) => {
    setFiles(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newErrors = findFormErrors();

    if (Object.keys(newErrors).length > 0) {
      setErrors(newErrors);
    } else {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("firstName", firstName);
      formData.append("lastName", lastName);
      formData.append("email", email);
      formData.append("city", city);
      formData.append("company", company);
      formData.append("howCanWeHelp", howCanWeHelp);
      formData.append("NDA", NDA);
      formData.append("file", files);

      const companyForm = `${process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_REQUEST}/company-form`;

      await Axios.post(companyForm, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
        .then(() => {
          setSuccessful(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${styles.container}`}>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row className={styles["contact__row"]}>
          <Col className={styles["contact__form-content"]}>
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>First Name*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("firstName", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                isInvalid={!!errors.firstName}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.firstName}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Last Name*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("lastName", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                isInvalid={!!errors.lastName}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.lastName}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Email*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("email", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                isInvalid={!!errors.email}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.email}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>City:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("city", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
              />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Company:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("company", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                isInvalid={!!errors.company}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.company}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>How we can help you?*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("howCanWeHelp", e.target.value)}
                as="textarea"
                row={4}
                isInvalid={!!errors.howCanWeHelp}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.howCanWeHelp}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Attach your files here:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control onChange={onFileUpload} type="file" />
            </Form.Group>

            <div className={styles["contact__button-checkbox"]}>
              <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                <Form.Check
                  defaultChecked={NDA}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setField("NDA", e.target.checked);
                  }}
                  type="checkbox"
                  label="Send NDA"
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Button
                disabled={successful}
                type="submit"
                variant="outline-dark"
              >
                {successful ? "Sent Successfully" : "SEND"}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Col>
```

Comment: is it throwing form validation error ? can you give me a screenshot ?

Comment: No, when I click on send it just doesn't work, nothing happens and when I upload the file then the send works.

Answer (score 0):

As you are validation on every submit clicked so it might be possible that some of your validation fails due to which you feel that your submit is not working.Try to debug your validations and place the line following line in the findFormErrors function and provide feedback:

```
const { firstName, lastName, email, city, company, howCanWeHelp, NDA } = form;
```

Code:

```
const Contact = () => {
  const [files, setFiles] = useState(null);
  const [successful, setSuccessful] = useState(false);
  const [form, setForm] = useState({});
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});

  const setField = (field, value) => {
    setForm({
      ...form,
      [field]: value,
    });

    if (!!errors[field])
      setErrors({
        ...errors,
        [field]: null,
      });
  };

 

  const findFormErrors = () => {
     const { firstName, lastName, email, city, company, howCanWeHelp, NDA } = form; // place it here
    const newErrors = {};

    if (!firstName || firstName === "") newErrors.firstName = "cannot be blank";
    if (!lastName || lastName === "") newErrors.lastName = "cannot be blank";
    if (!email || !email.includes("@")) newErrors.email = "enter a valid email";
    if (!company || company === "") newErrors.company = "cannot be blank";
    if (!howCanWeHelp || howCanWeHelp === "")
      newErrors.howCanWeHelp = "cannot be blank";

    return newErrors;
  };

  const onFileUpload = async (e) => {
    setFiles(e.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const newErrors = findFormErrors();

    if (Object.keys(newErrors).length > 0) {
      setErrors(newErrors);
    } else {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("firstName", firstName);
      formData.append("lastName", lastName);
      formData.append("email", email);
      formData.append("city", city);
      formData.append("company", company);
      formData.append("howCanWeHelp", howCanWeHelp);
      formData.append("NDA", NDA);
      formData.append("file", files);

      const companyForm = `${process.env.REACT_APP_PUBLIC_REQUEST}/company-form`;

      await Axios.post(companyForm, formData, {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
        },
      })
        .then(() => {
          setSuccessful(true);
        })
        .catch((error) => console.error(error));
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={`${styles.container}`}>
      <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <Row className={styles["contact__row"]}>
          <Col className={styles["contact__form-content"]}>
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>First Name*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("firstName", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                isInvalid={!!errors.firstName}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.firstName}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Last Name*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("lastName", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                isInvalid={!!errors.lastName}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.lastName}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Email*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("email", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                isInvalid={!!errors.email}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.email}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>City:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("city", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
              />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Company:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("company", e.target.value)}
                type="text"
                isInvalid={!!errors.company}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.company}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>How we can help you?*</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                onChange={(e) => setField("howCanWeHelp", e.target.value)}
                as="textarea"
                row={4}
                isInvalid={!!errors.howCanWeHelp}
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.howCanWeHelp}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3">
              <Form.Label>Attach your files here:</Form.Label>
              <Form.Control onChange={onFileUpload} type="file" />
            </Form.Group>

            <div className={styles["contact__button-checkbox"]}>
              <Form.Group className="mb-3">
                <Form.Check
                  defaultChecked={NDA}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setField("NDA", e.target.checked);
                  }}
                  type="checkbox"
                  label="Send NDA"
                />
              </Form.Group>
              <Button
                disabled={successful}
                type="submit"
                variant="outline-dark"
              >
                {successful ? "Sent Successfully" : "SEND"}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </Col>
```

Comment: And use Formik as it handle your state, onChange and errors too. You have to write validation Schema in Yup and it will validate the fields automatically

Comment: I tried to debug but couldn't find the reason for not submitting, will try formik and see thanks for suggestion.